# Cursor Not Moving Inside EditText for Custom Keyboard Input in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-cursor

I disabled the soft keyboard via:

```
   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

for an EditText view. As I expected, the keyboard gets disabled. I am using my own custom keyboard to input values.I am able to show the cursor at first or at last position or at specified position for the first time.

But I am facing problem to move the cursor at the position where I pressed that means I am unable to move the cursor within the text that I typed inside EditText.
Is there any solution to move the cursor inside the text for the custom keyboard input. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `editText1.setSelection(position)` to set the position of the cursor.
You can use `TextWatcher` class and get the length and put your cusor position.

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchBox1)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        String searchString = s.toString();
        int textLength = searchString.length();
        editText1.setSelection(textLength);         
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can helps someone still now. When you register the EditText, you have to catch the OnTouch event.

```
editText.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
    EditText et = (EditText) v;
    et.onTouchEvent(event);

    return false; //very important
 });
```

Don't miss the onClickListener which calls the *showCustomKeyboard(view)* method and hide the System's keyboard.